# Googleplace not saving to collection

Tags: meteor

I'm currently using [lukemadera:autoform-googleplace](https://github.com/lukemadera/meteor-autoform-googleplace) to save the users address. When the user saves their address it only saves the `fullAddress field` in the schema. I thought it broke the address up into its parts; street, state, zip etc. That way you could publish the address parts individually if required. I would like to be able to publish just the `state` in certain circumstances but I'm not sure how to do that since all I have is a fullAddress field string. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Path: `address.js`

```
Template.address.helpers({
  optsGoogleplace: function() {
    return {
      // type: 'googleUI',
      // stopTimeoutOnKeyup: false,
      googleOptions: {
        componentRestrictions: { country:'au' }
      }
    }
  },

});
```

Path: `address.html`

```
{{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" id="user" doc=currentUser type="update"}}
{{> afQuickField name="profile.address" type="googleplace" opts=optsGoogleplace class="form-control"}}
{{autoForm}}
```

Path: `Schema.js`

```
Schema.Address = new SimpleSchema({
        fullAddress: {
            type: String
        },
        lat: {
            type: Number,
            decimal: true
        },
        lng: {
            type: Number,
            decimal: true
        },
        geometry: {
            type: Object,
            blackbox: true
        },
        placeId: {
            type: String
        },
        street: {
            type: String,
            max: 100
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            max: 50
        },
        state: {
            type: String,
            regEx: /^A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[AU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]$/
        },
        zip: {
            type: String,
            regEx: /^[0-9]{5}$/
        },
        country: {
            type: String
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have it set up correctly, something like this should work:

```
Schemas = {};

Schemas.Address = new SimpleSchema({
    fullAddress: {
        type: String
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true
    },
    lng: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true
    },
    geometry: {
        type: Object,
        blackbox: true
    },
    placeId: {
        type: String
    },
    street: {
        type: String,
        max: 100
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        max: 50
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
    },
    zip: {
        type: String,
    },
    country: {
        type: String
    },
});



Schemas.MainSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    address: {
        type: Schemas.Address,
        optional: true
    }
});


MainSchema = new Mongo.Collection("MainSchema");

MainSchema.attachSchema(Schemas.MainSchema);


MainSchema.allow({
    insert: function () { return true; },
    update: function () { return true; },
    remove: function () { return true; }
});
```

Maybe check these out:

- https://github.com/lukemadera/meteor-autoform-googleplace/issues/24
- https://github.com/lukemadera/meteor-autoform-googleplace/issues/25
- http://www.curtismlarson.com/blog/2015/12/11/meteor-location-search-engine-mongodb-google-maps/

My only other guess is something is wrong with you google options helper. I'm not using that right now and the above setup works for me.